# I'm using Font.loadAsync and still getting error fontFamily "open-sans" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync

Tags: react-native

what's wrong with my code why wont it add the font to my app

I'm getting this error fontFamily "open-sans" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

  mport React from 'react';
  import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
  import { Font } from 'expo';

  this.state = {
        fontLoaded: false,
  }

Im using Font.loadAsync did i write it wrong?

```
async componentDidMount() {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        'OpenSans-Bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf')
      }).then(() => {
        this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
      });
    }
return (

     <View style={styles.container}>
     { this.state.fontLoaded === true ? (
       <React.Fragment>
</React.Fragment>
    ) : (<Text style={styles.inputText}>Loading... </Text>)
  }
      </View>
inputText: {
  fontSize: hp('3%'),
  color: '#5D5D5D',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  paddingVertical: hp('0.5%'),
  paddingLeft: wp('6.5%'),
  fontFamily: 'open-sans'

},
```

my pacakadge.json file

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "rnpm": {
      "assets": [
     "./assets/fonts/"
      ]
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From `SDK 33` the built-in modules of `Expo` must be installed. So you have to install a font module.

You can run `expo install expo-font`

The font name you registered with is different from the font name you want to use. And the conditional statement is wrong. After loading the font, make the text visible.

Change your font name

```js
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
...
this.state={
   fontLoaded: false
}
async componentDidMount() {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        'OpenSans-Bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf')
      });

        this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });

    }
return (

     <View style={styles.container}>
     { this.state.fontLoaded !== true ? (
       <React.Fragment>
</React.Fragment>
    ) : (<Text style={styles.inputText}>Loading... </Text>)
  }
      </View>
inputText: {
  fontSize: hp('3%'),
  color: '#5D5D5D',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  paddingVertical: hp('0.5%'),
  paddingLeft: wp('6.5%'),
  fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Bold'

},
```

Comment: Can you change the code for me because I'm not sure what you mean how should I change the conditional statement

Comment: @prog  Now you are supposed to express the text before loading the font. So I changed the font to show the text after loading. Look at my code.

Comment: i changed the font to fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Bold' and still getting the same error

Comment: @prog Is there a font file in your path?

Comment: i added a picture of the files

Comment: is there anything in your opinion wrong with what i have in my package.json file?

Comment: @prog Expo does not need to add a fonts file path. Delete rnpm.

Comment: Can you edit the code so I can see how it's supposed to look

Comment: And do you think me deleting rnpm should get it working or your just mentioning it as a side point

Comment: i tried everything but the font wasn't added still getting the same error to confirm you said i don't need to add any code to the package.json file?